# Differentiation under the integral sign??

Tags: integration, derivatives

When I tried to show this, I didn't get the integral of the derivative - only the other terms, and I have no idea why. Here's the working I have;

$\dfrac{d}{dx} \displaystyle\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)} f(x,t)\ dt$

Assuming $f$ integrable with antiderivative $F$:

$\dfrac{d}{dx} \displaystyle\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)} f(x,t)\ dt=\dfrac{d}{dx} [F(x,b(x))-F(x,a(x))]$

By chain rule:
\begin{align}
\dfrac{d}{dx} \displaystyle\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)} f(x,t)\ dt=& \left(\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial x}\dfrac{\partial x}{\partial x} + \dfrac{\partial F}{\partial b}\dfrac{\partial b}{\partial x}\right) - \left(\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial x}\dfrac{\partial x}{\partial x} + \dfrac{\partial F}{\partial a}\dfrac{\partial a}{\partial x}\right)\\
=& \dfrac{\partial F}{\partial b}\dfrac{\partial b}{\partial x}-\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial a}\dfrac{\partial a}{\partial x}\\
=&f(b)b'(x)-f(a)a'(x)
\end{align}

Where did the integral term disappear? I looked at other proofs online, but they're all that insanely ugly infinitesimal argument!

Comment: Check [Leibniz rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule).

Comment: This is why one should avoid the ugly $\partial x/\partial x$ notation! =) Rather, you can write $$D_1f(x,b(x))D_1b(x)-D_1f(x,a(x))D_1a(x)$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've ignored the points at which you evaluated those expressions. When you write:
$$ \left(\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial x}\dfrac{\partial x}{\partial x} + \dfrac{\partial F}{\partial b}\dfrac{\partial b}{\partial x}\right) - \left(\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial x}\dfrac{\partial x}{\partial x} + \dfrac{\partial F}{\partial a}\dfrac{\partial a}{\partial x}\right)$$
the $\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial x}$ terms don't cancel out, because they're really $\left(\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial x}\right)(x,b(x))$ and $\left(\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial x}\right)(x,a(x))$.

Comment: What a stupid mistake to make! Thanks a lot.

Comment: @FireGarden: kind of stupid, but also not all that uncommon when you use shorthand notation. We all make these once in a while. :)

Comment: My apologies @tomasz. The problem with using the mobile version of the site is that you are not updated about answers as you type. After posting I usually immediately close the page so I didn't realize you'd posted this whilst I was typing.